# flexible fields input to graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am using mongodb with [Graphql](http://graphql.org/) as described [Here](https://blog.risingstack.com/graffiti-mongoose-mongodb-for-graphql/) which is working well.but i have used mongodb schema as follows in one of my projects:

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema({
},{ strict: false });
module.exports=mongoose.model('schema',Schema);
```

As expected i can add any of the fields sent from client and this is the beauty of mongoDB(Schemaless).but i cannot see its support in graphql as if i want to add another field without defining it in schema.GraphQL is taking care of each field individually so is there any idea about it?